# Bitshifting a Java IntVector

Tags: java, vectorization

How can I perform a bitwise shift operation (<< or >>) directly on an [`IntVector`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/jdk.incubator.vector/jdk/incubator/vector/IntVector.html) using the Java Vector API?

I haven't been able to find anything obvious in the API to do this; the closest I've found is `myIntVec.lanewise(VectorOperators.ASHR, shiftAmt)` but this performs an additional `AND` operation on the shift amount.

Comment: Maybe `.mul(2)` and `.div(2)` would do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior is *correct*: pure `<<` for `int`s *also* performs an `&` operation on the shift amount.  The `&` correctly does the appropriate `&` operation for the values being operated on.

ASHR is *correctly* equivalent to `>>`.  LSHR is equivalent to `>>>`.  LSHL is equivalent to `<<`.  These all do the same thing as the normal operators do.

See [JLS 15.19](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19) for details.